# spring security is authenticating permitted requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I configured jwt auth provider for spring security. Below is my `SecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private final AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ).addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(false)
                    .maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see i've permitted requests matching `/auth/**`. But these endpoints are returning 401 anyway.

My auth controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder encoder, JwtUtils jwtUtils) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
            .body(new UserInfoResponse(userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                userDetails.getEmail()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: Username is already taken!");
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error: Email is already in use!");
        }

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
            signUpRequest.getEmail(),
            encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");
    }

    @PostMapping("/signout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logoutUser() {
        ResponseCookie cookie = jwtUtils.getCleanJwtCookie();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString())
            .body("You've been signed out!");
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class SignupRequest {
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class UserInfoResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
}
```

Could someone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?

===== Update =====

Here's my AuthTokenFilter

```
@Service
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation as to why you chose to include an AbstractHttpConfigurer?

Comment: Hi @LuigiWoodhouse. `http.csrf()` is deprecated in latest version of spring-security and marked for removal.
I've used `AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable` as lambda function. However, i've changed `http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)` to `http.csrf(c -> c.disable()) `but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You're not getting redirected to something which is authenticated, like `/error`?

Comment: permitted doesn't mean don't apply the security filters. The problem is probably in your `authenticationJwtTokenFilter` which tries to validate/check a token and it does show too eagerly and throwing an exception when there is no token.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've updated my question with `JwtTokenFilter`. i'm not actually throwing any exception when jwt token does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Add request matcher for authenticated endpoint and permitting any other requests worked.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(c -> c.disable())
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .build();
    }
```

This is strange. Basically `anyRequest().authenticated()` at the end overrides the `permitAll` on request matcher.

So, decided to add matchers for authenticated endpoints and permit everything else.

Feel free to post you thoughts and alternate solutions if you think this is not an optimal solution

Comment: So basically open everything up and close everything else, which is, from a security perspective a bad idea. You want to close everything and open only what you need. The fact that opening up everything makes it work, shows that the error is probably not your `/auth` mapping but something else that gets called. You want to enable DEBUG logging for Spring Security and check what is actually leading to that 401.

Answer (score 0):

For springboot 3.1.1 you can refer below code for security :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeRequests().
            requestMatchers("/category/add")
            .authenticated()
            .requestMatchers("/authenticate","/register").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

CustomAuthentcationManager :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```